# Migration versions across multiple directories

Tags: migration, version, flyway

If I want to organize my migrations in multiple directories (let's say I'm using SQL migrations, and under the "sql" directory I have a "main" directory and then a "special" directory).

So under sql/main I have "V1.1__some_change" etc.

Then I want to put other migrations under sql/special as well. But the migration version numbers have to be distinct across all the directories, e.g., I couldn't put "V1.1__some_other_change" in sql/special as it would cause a conflict.

But it's not that easy to manage a linear version number across many different directories. Is there a good approach to solve this issue?

Hope this question is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it all depends on why special is **"special"** and how it is **related to "main"**.

If they have the **same lifecycle** you could use a different numbering scheme (whole number in main, point releases in special) or track the assigned migration number in a shared resource (whiteboard, wiki page, ...) to make it easy to know which the next available one is.

If they have **separate lifecycles**, you could have separate Flyway instances tracking them (each with a different flyway.table).

Comment: Thanks. They do have the same lifecycle. Using "main" and "special" was actually a bad example. Your idea of dot releases for special probably would have worked but all the directories are really of the same "importance". They're just divided by subject matter for organization purposes. For now I've decided to just use a full date/timestamp as the version numbers so that they're more or less guaranteed to be unique and also maintain migration order across all the directories.

Answer (score 3):

Today I faced kind of a same issue. I updated Flyway 1.7 to the latest release being 2.0.3.
And I noted that migrations don't work anymore as they did in version 1.7.

We use different sub folders of the base folder (db.migrations) to hold migrations for different database schemes, which have **separate lifecycles** with their own schema_version tables:

```
src->main->resources->db.migrations
 ->business_partitions
     -> V1_1__BUSINESS_PARTITION_INDEXES.sql
     -> V1__BUSINESS_PARTITIOS.sql
 ->tech
     -> V1_1__TECH_CERTIFICATES_AND_DECRYPTORS_TABLES.sql
     -> V1__TECH.sql
     -> V2__JMS.sql
 ->view
     -> V1__PARTITION11_DB_CREATION_SCRIPT_VIEWS.sql
```

When we performed our db migrations today using the following lines in Java:

```
Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
flyway.setDataSource(dataSource);
flyway.setLocations("db.migrations.business_partitions");
flyway.migrate();
```

no migrations were done.

I dived a little in the flyway source code and discovered the problem was that the location was filtered out in the mergeLocations() method of the CompositeMigrationResolver class.

There, my location was filtered out since business_partitions is a subfolder of db.migrations, being the default value for BaseDir and BasePackage.

I worked around by setting the BaseDir and the BasePackage explicitly:

```
flyway.setBaseDir("db.migrations.business_partitions");
flyway.setBasePackage("db.migrations.business_partitions");
```

I read that those two methods will be deprecated in flyway 3, so maybe this will also fix our problem.

Comment: These methods caused a lot of trouble, and are already gone in SCM. This should once again work as expected in 2.1